# How to represent Tcl code output graphically?

Tags: tcl

Want to represent Tcl output data graphically using tree, graph, block-diagram, flow-chart etc. What will be best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Tcl has bindings to a number of GUI toolkits, but by far the most commonly used one is [Tk](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tk). I've used it to write an IDE in the past (for a very weird graphical programming system that nobody cares about any more) so it is quite capable. (The [`text`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/text) hypertext widget and the [`canvas`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/canvas) hypergraphics widget are both very interesting for doing complex applications around.)

But for charting and graphing there are other libraries. In particular, integrations with [graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/) and [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) are (very!) good ways to make many ways of displaying data that have some integration capabilities with Tk, [RBC](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Refactored+BLT+Components) has some good widgets (especially for live plotting), and there are Tklib modules (especially [plotchart](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/plotchart)) that may also be highly relevant.

You'll need to ask a more specific question to get a more helpful answer. I'm also sure I've missed things.

Comment: There's a general plan to adopt RBC into Tk, but that's a _very_ complex project that depends a lot on how we want to evolve Tk itself.

Comment: Also, for general plotting it is sometimes easiest to just spit out the data in a form that you can load into a webpage or manipulate in a spreadsheet. There are libraries to help with both of those too.

Comment: Thanks @Donal. Was looking for making block diagrams specifically.